# Is there a way to find all asynchronous calls (promises) in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to figure out which promise is causing the following unhandled exception and I wonder if there is a way to list all promises at certain point in order to detect the issue or alternatively add call stack information:

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [run `node` with `--trace-uncaught`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--trace-uncaught) to get stack traces for uncaught exceptions.

Also [see the `unhandledRejection` event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection).

Comment: I've tried both of this options but it didn't helped discover additional information on the origin of the rejected promise.
The unhandledRejection event didn't triggered and the trace data is too generic:

```Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)```

Comment: Well, based on that information already you can tell it's some `connect` call, and you see where it's trying to connect to, which narrows things down a lot if you ask me.

Comment: sadly not, because there are many different flows which trying to connect to the same host/port and I wanted to narrow it down.
I eventually found the issue, but wonder why there is no built-in capability to allow easier diagnostic.